# How can I find out why a gem bundle has locked a gem at a specific version?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to specify a version of the [thrift gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/thrift) in my gem file.

```
gem 'thrift', "~> 0.6.0"
```

When I trying to run `bundle install`, I get this error:

```
You have requested:
  thrift ~> 0.6.0

The bundle currently has thrift locked at 0.5.0.
Try running `bundle update thrift`
```

How can I find out what is causing it to be locked at the earlier version? Would it be in the requirements of another gem I have listed in the gem file?

Or is it just being caused by the fact that the installed version is 0.5.0, and specifying a version in the gem file won't update an installed gem?

Comment: can you show us Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turns out just running `bundle update thrift` will show you what is locking the version:

```
$ bundle update thrift

Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "thrift":
  In Gemfile:
    evernote depends on
      thrift (~> 0.5.0)

    thrift (0.6.0)
```